# acro acronym not recognized inside the soul package's strikeout command

Tags: soul, acro, strikeout

I'm finding that if I use an `acro` acronym inside a `soul` strikeout command, I get errors about the acronym not being defined.  Here is my Minimal Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{acro} % Handling of acronyms
\usepackage{soul} % Strikeout font
%\soulfont{\ac}{1} % Protect's \ac command from soul
\DeclareAcronym{abc}{ short = ABC, long =AbBraCadabra }
\begin{document}

Try strikeout \st{abc}

Try acronym \ac{abc}

% This causes error about undefined acronym '{abc}'
Try strikeout acronym \st{\ac{abc}}

\end{document}
```

The commented-out \soulfont command is an attempt protect the \ac command, as per the soul packcage documentation (section "Adding font commands").  It causes the following error

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\SOUL@do #1->\SOUL@scan 
                        #1\SOUL@stop
```

Is there any way around this without abandoning the acro package?

Comment: Quick fix: `\st{{\ac{abc}}}` – doesn't help if the acronym is used for the first time, though…

Comment: I would have thought that `\soulregister{\ac}{1}` should work but it doesn't…

Comment: Thanks, clemens.  I managed to rewrite around the need, but your partial solution is good for reference in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example modifies egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367656/16967) and puts `\ac` inside a box (prevents line breaks) and uses the box inside of `\st`. This also works for the first usage of acronyms:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro} % Handling of acronyms
\usepackage{soul} % Strikeout font

\DeclareAcronym{abc}{ short = ABC, long =AbBraCadabra }

\newsavebox\tmpbox

\begin{document}

Try strikeout \st{abc}

Try strikeout acronym \sbox\tmpbox{\ac{abc}}\st{foo {\usebox\tmpbox} bar}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, Heiko.  It gets into boxes, which I will need to get familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

You can brace the usage of `\ac` inside `\st`. However, it will not work for not yet used acronyms.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro} % Handling of acronyms
\usepackage{soul} % Strikeout font

\DeclareAcronym{abc}{ short = ABC, long =AbBraCadabra }

\begin{document}

Try strikeout \st{abc}

Try acronym \ac{abc}

Try strikeout acronym \st{abc {\ac{abc}} abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]